Problem with createContext and useContext in Next Js
Hi I am new to next Js and cant solve this error. I dont know what is the error and how to explain it.Here are some photos and code

app/layout.tsx
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import {StateContext} from "@/context/StateContext";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">   
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <StateContext>
          <Toaster></Toaster>
        {children}
        </StateContext>
       
        </body>
    </html>
  );
}


context/StateContext.tsx  contain Context
"use client";

import React,{createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, Children} from "react";
import {toast} from'react-hot-toast';
import {product_attribute} from '@/components/Interface'

export const Context = createContext<product_attribute| undefined>(undefined);

export const StateContext = ({children} : any) =>{
    const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState();
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState();
    const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState();
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

    const incQty = () => {
        setQty((prevQty) => prevQty + 1);
    }

    const decQty = () => {
        setQty((prevQty) => {
            if(prevQty - 1 < 1) return 1;
            return prevQty - 1
        });
    }

    return(
        <Context.Provider 
        value={{
            qty,
            incQty,
            decQty,
        }}>
        {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(Context);
    return context;
};

components/Interface.tsx contain product_attribute
export interface SimplifiedProduct{
    _id : string;
    imageUrl : string;
    name : string;
    price : number;
    slug : string;
}

export interface fullProduct{
    id : string;
    image : any;
    details : string;
    name : string;
    price : number;
    slug : string;
}

export interface product_attribute{
    qty : number,
    incQty : () => void,
    decQty : () => void,
}

product/[slug]/page.tsx where i want to use Context

import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import { Navbar, Footer } from '@/components'
import { client, urlFor } from '@/lib/client'
import { fullProduct, SimplifiedProduct } from '@/components/Interface';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus, AiFillStar,AiOutlineStar} from 'react-icons/ai';
import {getProduct} from '@/components/Product';
import Product from '@/components/Product';
import ImageGallery from '@/components/ImageGallery';
import {Context} from '@/context/StateContext';

const ProductDetails = async({params}:{params : {slug : string}}) => {
const data = await getData(params.slug);
const products : SimplifiedProduct[] = await getProduct();
const  {qty, incQty, decQty} = useContext(Context);

  return (
    
    <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <div className='product-detail-container'>
            <div>
                <ImageGallery images={data.image}/>
            </div>
            <div className='product-detail-desc'>
                <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                <div className='reviews'>
                    <div>
                        <AiFillStar></AiFillStar>
                        <AiFillStar></AiFillStar>
                        <AiFillStar></AiFillStar>
                        <AiFillStar></AiFillStar>
                        <AiOutlineStar></AiOutlineStar>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        {20}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <h4>Details : </h4>
                <p>{data.details}</p>
                <p className='price'>Rs{data.price}</p>
                <div className='quantity'>
                    <h3>Quantity:</h3>
                    <p className='quantity-desc'>
                        <span className='minus' onClick={decQty}><AiOutlineMinus/></span>
                        <span className='num' >{qty}</span>
                        <span className='plus' onClick={incQty}><AiOutlinePlus/></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="buttons">
                  <button type="button" className="add-to-cart" >Add to Cart</button>
                  <button type="button" className="buy-now" >Buy Now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="maylike-products-wrapper">
          <h2>You may also like</h2>
          <div className="marquee">
            <div className="maylike-products-container track">
            {products.map((item:any) => (
                <Product key={item._id} data={item} />
              ))}

            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
        <Footer/>
     </div>
  )
}

async function getData(slug :string){
    const Query = `
  *[_type == "product" && slug.current == "${slug}"][0]{
_id,
  name,
  price,
  image,
  slug,
  details,
}
  `;
    const product : fullProduct = await client.fetch(Query);
    return product;
  }

export default ProductDetails

Error Occurings
I tried to use "use client" in [slug]/page.tsx it didnt resolve anything

Try changing your exported context to the following
export const Context = createContext<product_attribute>({
  qty: 1,
  incQty: () => {},
  decQty: () => {},
});

  const { qty, decQty, incQty } = useContext(Context);

  return <div>{qty}</div>;

Try replacing the (product_attribute | undefined) with just (product_attribute), and providing just some mock initial values to satisfy typescript (These inital values would be overridden any way in your StateContext function so they are just to stop typescript from causing errors)
Or if you want to keep (product_attribute | undefined) then try this approach
  const context = useContext(Context);

  return <div>{context?.qty}</div>;

export const Context = createContext<product_attribute | undefined>(undefined);

dont de-construct the context, and when you use any property from it add ? (question mark) before the dot (.), this tells the javascript not to throw an error if the property was not found and satisfy typescript, you can use this inside of your product/[slug]/page.tsx or any place you want to use the context.
please inform me if this helped, or I can take a deeper dive into it :)

Hey i tried your solution where i replace <product_attribute|undefined> with just <product_attribute> but the error is still the same even if i used context?.qty and kept the undefined  and even combining the two solution where i give those initial values and use context?.qty
This is the error : TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext) is not a function
at ProductDetails (./app/product/[slug]/page.tsx:27:70)

I added the photo of the error in the post, for some reason it wasnt showing it

@SilentPrime
So  If I understood you correctly the original error was resolved and you have a new error which is --> 0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext
right ?

@SilentPrime
regarding this error -->0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext
its really confusing I had it before and I followed these steps and it would resolve, try them
1- try to delete the .next folder in the root dir and rerun the application
2- add "use client" to the top of the page.tsx page

To answer your previous question - No the error is the same even after i use the solutions.
And after implementing your latest solution - it is giving me this error Error: Request error while attempting to reach is https://**********.apicdn.sanity.io/v2024-07-28/data/query/production............

Although I am not sure which page.tsx you were talking about so the above error was coming product/[slug]/page.tsx and this error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at ProductDetails (./app/product/[slug]/page.tsx:27:70) was coming when i use "use client" in the normal page.tsx(So now both product/[slug]/page.tsx and app/page.tsx)
